# What is MZFW and what will happen if an airplane exceeded this weight?

Tags: aircraft-design, weight-and-balance

What is MZFW and what will happen if an airplane exceeded this weight?

Is that the wing root experiences the highest bending moment under the loading condition corresponding to Maximum Zero Fuel Weight (MZFW)?

or

According to Boeing W&B study.
[image: W&B MZFW 01]

I am truly confused about those concepts.
Are those concepts different between GA and transport category due to GA without center fuel tank?
[image: W&B MZFW 02]
[image: W7B MZFW 03]

Comment: What is the source of the slides presented here?

Comment: What is your doubt exactly? The naming convention? The plot of the moment? The fact that the center tank is filled after the wing tanks?